# Gifts in luggage

Tags: customs-and-immigration, luggage, germany, gifts

I'll be flying from the USA back to Germany. I have bought several gifts for family.

This includes:

- A brand new laptop
- makeup
- clothes
- wallets
- perfumes

Is this going to cause a problem at the airport. We are flying from Charleston to Washington then to Germany. I have heard US customs sometimes cause problems. What are the things I can do to avoid such a hassle?

Comment: Why are you asking about US customs, when you're leaving the US?

Comment: Cause i have heard ppl get stopped by them and asked why they are taking items with tags. I don't know what you mean by your question. Sorry maybe i misunderstood

Comment: US customs doesn't inspect people **leaving** the US. You will have to pass **German** customs.

Comment: What is the value of the gifts? Will you be packing all the items into hold luggage? Typically one big hassle when ‘leaving’ is falling foul of restrictions on what is allowed in carry on.

Comment: Umm okay thankyou

Comment: Everything will be packed in checked luggage

Comment: I would suggest not packing the brand new laptop in checked luggage.  It is possible that you will never see your checked luggage again, and a brand new laptop would be a choice target for theft. And every man and has dog already has keys for TSA approved locks (and if you don't use TSA approved locks, they *will* be cut off)

Comment: And checked luggage often gets handled rough so damage is also likely.

Comment: @MJeffryes It's rare anyway for US customs to inspect people leaving. Unless you have controlled goods in your bags or something deemed by the authorities to be of security importance on your laptop it's not something to worry about. I agree, do NOT check the laptop. If necessary, take it out of the box and carry the laptop itself. As happend to me once, the empty luggage turned up a couple days later.

Comment: Be very careful using the word "Gift" in Germany ( ). "Gift" is a German word for  deadly poison (). In American( ) English, the word "Gift" is a happy thing.  The word "Gift" means . In American English, a gift is an item given to someone with friendship or love. In Germany, the word "Gift" is very bad. The German word for   is "Geschenk" .... or maybe..."Verleihung".

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon "Verleihung"`? surely not. that would mean "bestowal, award ceremony" or "lending", "loaning", "rental". A bestowal is the act of giving a gift, not a gift itself. An alternative to "gift" would be the word "present", if you want to speak English.

Comment: @PeterM I would suggest not packing a laptop in checked luggage anywhere. It's a safety concern and they don't even need to be thieves to remove devices with LiPo batteries, throw them away and possibly apply further charges/measures against the passenger.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon That's just bullshit. Germans, as almost everyone else, are of course aware that words have different meanings in different languages and would not react if a word comes up in an English sentence, which means something else in German. If you speak English with a German person, you simply do exactly that: speak English. You don't have to awkwardly search for new terms or slide in a German word or two just to prevent usage of certain English words. At least not, when you do that by following your advice and use German words with a completely different meaning.

Comment: @user3819867 The [TSA](https://www.faa.gov/hazmat/packsafe/more_info/?hazmat=20) only *suggests* that laptops should not be checked "*Devices containing lithium metal or lithium ion batteries (laptops, smartphones, tablets, etc.) should be carried in carry-on baggage when possible*".  They do not outright ban them (as they do "spare" batteries, as mentioned in the same article).  So there should be no additional legal risk to anyone putting a laptop in checked luggage.

Comment: @PeterM It seems like you are generally right. The referred FAA guide has the "must be completely powered off and protected to prevent unintentional activation or damage" criteria. This is ambiguous at best, some airlines and countries may have stronger controls or the TSA agent can decide to mess with you based on the vagueness.

Answer (score 20):

The rules for importing goods to Germany as a traveller [are here](https://www.zoll.de/EN/Private-individuals/Travel/Entering-Germany/Duties-and-taxes/Travellers-allowances/travellers-allowances_node.html). Since none of the special categories apply to the goods you've brought (ie, they are not tobacco or alcohol) and you are travelling by air, the duty free allowance is the value of €430.

This is the total value of goods that you may bring in duty free. For any goods that exceed the total value you must pay duty on the *total value* of the items which exceed €430. By way of example, let's say the total value of the makeup, clothes, wallets and perfumes is €400, and the laptop is worth €500. In this case, you can bring everything except the laptop in according to your duty free allowance, but you will need to pay duty on the total value of the laptop.

The calculation of duty is [quite complex](https://www.zoll.de/EN/Private-individuals/Travel/Entering-Germany/Duties-and-taxes/Exceeding-travellers-allowances/exceeding-travellers-allowances_node.html). But the customs officers will do it for you. Assuming you are over the duty free limit you will need to pass through the red channel when entering Germany to declare your goods.

Comment: Might be worth adding: Use the red channel when in doubt, e.g. because the value is roughly 430€. AFAIK, there is no penalty in using the red channel when it turns out you have no goods to declare; while there sure is a penalty if you take the green channel and are found carrying goods to declare during a random inspection.

Comment: Once you have declared your goods (you need to have the invoices handy) the officials will calculate how much duty you have to pay. It may be zero. If it is > 0 then you just smile and pay it. This is OK, no crime has been committed. Do not argue. Do not try to hide anything.

Comment: FWIW: German customs is fairly relaxed as compared most other countries. I've entered the country dozens of times and NEVER got asked anything by customs. In fact, the one time I actually chose to declare something, it was huge pain just to find an officer on duty. CAVEAT: I'm white and German looking so not exactly a target for profiling.